# express.js how show image?

Tags: node.js

I have images in /public folder and I want to show them..simply like this: `<img src="a.jpg">`

My app.js code

```
var express = require('express')
  , app = express()
  , http = require('http')
  , server = http.createServer(app)
  , io = require('socket.io').listen(server);

server.listen(8080);    
app.use('/public', express.static(__dirname + "/public"));
```

If I open it in localhost this error is still showing

```
NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://localhost:8080/public/a.jpg"
```

Comment: I tested your code and it's working fine.

Comment: hmm really? So why it is not working on my localhost?

Comment: Are you sure that your express app is pointing to the right public folder?

Comment: yes, but I don't know what was that..now it works, but I didn't changed any code..and 1 minute ago there was same code and it didn't worked.. thanks for helping me

Comment: Yes it's strange. You're welcome anyways.

Comment: Is it inside public or in image folder inside public ?

Comment: it is inside public folder

Answer (score 3):

in your case it is enough to write:

```
app.use(express.static('public'));
```

it will serve directly the public folder.

an image in this path `/public/images/somePhoto.png` would be shown like that: `http://localhost:8080/images/somePhoto.png`

source: https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html

Answer (score 1):

You need to drop the /public/ bit from your URL to your image.
So it becomes just `http://localhost:8080/a.jpg`

Comment: I disagree! `app.use('/public', express.static(__dirname + "/public"));` should serve files with `/public` pathname prefix.

Comment: uf now I don't understand what I am doing bad

Comment: @fardjad i disagree with your disagreement! http://expressjs.com/faq.html - a request to "GET /javascripts/jquery.js" would first check "./public/javascripts/jquery.js"

Comment: @alexjamesbrown as it says in `How can I prefix a pathname for serving statics?`, it exposes the `req.url` without the prefix (passed as the first argument) to `express.static` middleware.

Comment: @alexjamesbrown In addition to my previous comment: that doesn't mean that the request URL shouldn't have `/public` prefix in this case.

Answer (score 0):

handling static files in express
You simply need to pass the name of the directory where you keep your static assets, to the express.static middleware to start serving the files directly. 
For example, if you keep your assests in a folder called public, you can use
`app.use(express.static('public'))` as follows, my images are in `public\images`

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
app.use(express.static('public'));
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.send('Hello World');
})
var server = app.listen(8081, function () {
var host = server.address().address
var port = server.address().port
console.log("Example app listening at http://%s:%s", host, port)
})
```

save the code above to server.js

`$ node server.js`

Now open http://127.0.0.1:8081/images/logo.png in any browser and image will show up

Answer (score -1):

I removed the backslash before the "public".

In my app.js or server.js, I changed this:

```
app.use(express.static('/public'));
```

to this:

```
app.use(express.static('public'));
```

Just in case anyone still has this issue.